Can one be mistaken as to what one desires?
This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: Can one be mistaken as to what one is thinking?. The present question is about desires. Can a person be mistaken as to what they desire? Personally, I believe that desires are transparent. However, I am slightly less sure about the transparency of desires than about thoughts. But what have philosophers written about this topic? And can I see some references?

The answer may be trivial based on how you define desire as a concept.The Wikipedia article on Philosophy of desire makes clear that for Lacan, desire as such must be articulated (and therefore presumably known) in order to exist.

"be mistaken" has an extremely large margin; "what one desires" is also not at all sth clear: Do you know what you desire if you're deliberating over what to do? if so, why do you have to first deliberate? Do you know what you desire ('quit smoking'), if you cannot follow up with action? (see: akrasia).

Much or maybe most of the relevant modern literature is going to be psych literature. Alas, much of it is going to reference fraudulent Freud, whose double curse upon psych was being completely full of crap and also extremely insightful.

Apropos of Romans 7. "I do not understand what I do. For what I want to do I do not do, but what I hate I do. [...] For I have the desire to do what is good, but I cannot carry it out. I do not do the good I want to do, but the evil I do not want to do—this I keep on doing. [...] I see another law at work in me, waging war against the law of my mind and making me a prisoner."

That the answer is yes is much less controversial than in the case of thoughts, since desires are typically interpreted as dispositions to act they are not even presupposed to be luminous. Dispositions only manifest when the context is right, there is little reason to expect that people would know how they are disposed to act in its absence. That people are  surprised by their own actions, disappointed when getting what they thought they wanted, etc., confirms it. "Be careful what you wish for" is there as a warning that one may not really wish what they think they wish.
